# Regex for Url Angular Validation

Tags: regex, angular

Im using Reactive Form. I have 1 field called URL. 
Example

```
url: 'iphone',
url: 'iphone-black'
```

I handle and now I have

```
abc.com/iphone
abc.com/iphone-black
```

I need a regex for Validator pattern to check this field (start & end with word (allow 0-9, a-z, A-Z), hyphen between word (allow 0-9, a-z, A-Z), no space, no special charater)

True case

```
'iphone'
'iPhone-black'
'IPHONE-7-black'
```

False case

```
' iphone'
' iPhone '
'iph$one'
'iPhone -7-black'
'iPhone black'
'-iPhone- '
```

Comment: You can use this [`^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/ARg39A/1)

Comment: Tks @Code Maniac, it work, but I just update false case, with your pattern '-iphone-' still valid

Comment: You can just use `startsWith` and `endWith` simply no need to complicate pattern, i.e `str.startsWith('_') && str,endsWith('_') ? false : /^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/.test(str)`

Comment: try this `^[\w-]+`. it should work.

Comment: I write a function like @Code Maniac mentioned and it work

Comment: @Shivam Singh Ur solution is wrong, when I have 'a' it invalid, I think u misunderstand my question

Comment: I think you are looking for `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/IfmAWk/1

Comment: Sorry too late, it worked, Tks @The fourth bird